# Eliminating words that have two or more periods together in Python using Regex?

Tags: python, regex

For example, if I have a string:

```
"I really..like something like....that"
```

I want to get only:

```
"I something"
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does it have to be regex? Why not `' '.join(word for word in text.split() if '..' not in word)`?

Comment: Should it work for this string:  `I really..like something like....that fdsafdsafdsf rdas...dsafaf ....fdfff ....ffff....`?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it with regex; you can to use below regex to remove them:

```
r"[^\.\s]+\.{2,}[^\.\s]+"g
```

[**[ Regex Demo ]**](https://regex101.com/r/dlZXAf/2)

Regex explanation:

```
[^\.\s]+       at least one of any character instead of '.' and a white space
\.{2,}         at least two or more '.'
[^\.\s]+       at least one of any character instead of '.' and a white space
```

or this regex:

```
r"\s+[^\.\s]+\.{2,}[^\.\s]+"g
  ^^^  for including spaces before those combination
```

[**[ Regex Demo ]**](https://regex101.com/r/dlZXAf/4)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a regex explicitly you could use the following.

```
import re

string = "I really..like something like....that"
with_dots = re.findall(r'\w+[.]+\w+', string)

split = string.split()
without_dots = [word for word in split if word not in with_dots]
```

The solution provided by rawing also works in this case.

```
' '.join(word for word in text.split() if '..' not in word)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may very well use boundaries in combination with lookarounds:

```
\b(?<!\.)(\w+)\b(?!\.)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/jB78X7/2/).

---

Broken apart, this says:

```
\b        # a word boundary
(?<!\.)   # followed by a negative lookbehind making sure there's no '.' behind
\w+       # 1+ word characters
\b        # another word boundary
(?!\.)    # a negative lookahead making sure there's no '.' ahead
```

---

As a whole `Python` snippet:

```
import re

string = "I really..like something like....that"

rx = re.compile(r'\b(?<!\.)(\w+)\b(?!\.)')

print(rx.findall(string))
# ['I', 'something']
```